# laravel seeder multi language

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have build multi language website using laravel.i have seed all my tables expect post table
i need to chunk 1000 rows in database with two differnet language i have used this code

```
   for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
            $days = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28'];
            $months = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08'];
            $post_date = "2020-" . Arr::random($months) . "-" . Arr::random($days) . " 01:01:01";
            $post_title = $faker->sentence(mt_rand(3, 6), true);
            $post_artitle = $arfaker->sentence(mt_rand(3, 6), true);


            $posts[] = [
                'title'         =>  ['en' => $post_title , 'ar' => $post_artitle],
                'slug'          =>  ['en' => Str::slug($post_title) , 'ar' => Str::slug($post_artitle)],
                'description'   =>  ['en' => $faker->paragraph() , 'ar' => $arfaker->paragraph()],
                'status'        =>  rand(0, 1),
                'comment_able'  =>  rand(0, 1),
                'user_id'       =>  $user->random(),
                'category_id'   =>  $categories->random(),
                'created_at'    =>  $post_date,
                'updated_at'    =>  $post_date,

            ];

        }

        $chunks = array_chunk($posts, 500);
        foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
            Post::insert($chunk);
        }
```

but i got error array to string conversion. what is the correct way to seed these data .thanks in advance

Comment: You are probably trying to store an array in a string field, for example in the case of the `title`. Or is this field a JSON field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are storing array in json field, this is why you see this error.

you should encode it first.

```
$posts[] = [
            'title'         => json_encode( ['en' => $post_title , 'ar' => $post_artitle]),
            'slug'          =>json_encode(  ['en' => Str::slug($post_title) , 'ar' => Str::slug($post_artitle)]),
                'description'   => json_encode( ['en' => $faker->paragraph() , 'ar' => $arfaker->paragraph()]),
                'status'        =>  rand(0, 1),
                'comment_able'  =>  rand(0, 1),
                'user_id'       =>  $user->random(),
                'category_id'   =>  $categories->random(),
                'created_at'    =>  $post_date,
                'updated_at'    =>  $post_date,

            ];
```

Comment: only one problem is arabic letter save in (\u062a\u062c\u0631\u0628\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0635 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u0628\u064a )

Comment: i have solved it by adding option JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE